# DD4T with AppFabric Caching?

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t

Has anyone considered or already using DD4T with AppFabric caching? If so, which approach have you implemented (see possibilities from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917135/developing-net-mvc3-application-for-caching-using-appfabric-1-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are using AppFabric on our current DD4T project and use it as a distributed data cache. XML from DD4T is cached in AppFabric and in our scaled out scenario all servers connect to this AppFabric cachecluster.

You could also use it as a distributed outputcache (check out the local cache option for performance). One server fills the outputcache, other servers are benefiting from it.

Comment: Albert, how are you invalidating your cache items? When I last checked a ChangeMonitor object couldn't be used with AppFabric so you'd need another process to check last published dates.

Comment: We use a storage extension. As soon as someone publishes an item, the AppFabric cache is invalidated.

Comment: So that has to be written in Java right?

Comment: Indeed. The Storage Extension is in Java. It then puts an invalidationmessage (XML) in a queue (ActiveMq). A .NET service receives this messages and invalidates the item in AppFabric.